# Как вывести по фамилии в алфавитном порядке и если повторяется то обнулить

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Остальная часть кода ниже

Output structure records by surname in alphabeticalorder;if duplicates-NULL

```
struct St


for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    cout << i << "\n Please input your personal data \n";
    cin >> student[i].surname;        
    cin >> student[i].name;
    cin >> student[i].gender;
    cin >> student[i].age;
    cin >> student[i].citizenship;
}

cout << "\n\n";


    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (student[i].surname == student[i + 1].surname)
        {
            student[i].surname = '\0';
            student[i].name = '\0';
            student[i].gender = '\0';
            student[i].age = '\0';
            student[i].citizenship = '\0';

        }

        cout << student[i].surname << "\n";
        cout << student[i].name << "\n";
        cout << student[i].gender << "\n";
        cout << student[i].age << "\n";
        cout << student[i].citizenship << "\n";
```

Comment: struct St
{
    char surname[20];
    char name[20];
    char gender[3];
    int age;
    char citizenship[5];
};


int main()
{
    St student[3]; int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cout << i << "\n Please input your personal data \n";

Comment: Для начала отсортировать, ваше казненное величество...

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct St {
    string surname;
    string name;
    string gender;
    string age;
    string citizenship;
};

bool comp(St& a, St& b) {
    return a.surname < b.surname;
}

int main() {
    St student[100];
    int n = 3; // количество учеников
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << i << " Please input your personal data: \n";
        cin >> student[i].surname;
        cin >> student[i].name;
        cin >> student[i].gender;
        cin >> student[i].age;
        cin >> student[i].citizenship;
    }
    sort(student, student + n, comp);
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) {
        if (student[i].surname != student[i + 1].surname) {
            cout << student[i].surname << "\n";
            cout << student[i].name << "\n";
            cout << student[i].gender << "\n";
            cout << student[i].age << "\n";
            cout << student[i].citizenship << "\n";
        }
    }
    cout << student[n - 1].surname << "\n";
    cout << student[n - 1].name << "\n";
    cout << student[n - 1].gender << "\n";
    cout << student[n - 1].age << "\n";
    cout << student[n - 1].citizenship << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```